# Android php connection

Tags: javascript, php, android, web-hosting

If I'm trying to get the html source of a website with AndroidStudio (through my app) the pages shows up different content with the ending message and i'm using no web view or somthing like that.

I have a php file in a hostweb and i want to show the message in a textview :

```
<?php
echo "hello from the other side";
?>
```

and my android code is :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView text;
FloatingActionButton fab;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    try
    {
        String myurl = "http://keeplearning.eb2a.com/hello.php";
        new  MyAsyncTaskgetNews().execute(myurl);
    }catch (Exception ex){}


}


private class MyAsyncTaskgetNews  extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String NewsData="";
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            NewsData=Stream2String(in);
            in.close();

            publishProgress(NewsData );

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        try {
            text.setText(values[0]);
        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
public String Stream2String(InputStream inputStream) {
    BufferedReader bureader=new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line ;
    String Text="";
    try{
        while((line=bureader.readLine())!=null) {
            Text+=line;
        }
        inputStream.close();
    }catch (Exception ex){}
    return Text;
}
```

}

and when i run it i get this error

Activate JavaScript in your Browser.  
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZETM3.png)

any idea what should i do ? or i enable javascript ?

Comment: Where exactly does this error come? Can you share the logcat?

Comment: i has added a pictures showing the error@JoeyPinto

Comment: Check my solution, i have faced this before

Comment: yes i did thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP request cannot handle javascript code. The URL you have provided probably executes some javascript to send a window.location redirect to another page. HTTP Request cannot handle this as it doesnt execute javscript like your browser foes and reads the HTML as is .

To fix this you must move your redirection code to PHP itself. Use the PHP header() function to do this.

Answer (score 0):

thank you all i appreciate it but i found the error from my webhosting once i changed the host it really i'm using 000webhost now.

the first webhosting was running a bot that enable javascript.

i appreciate all of your hard works. ^_^

Answer (score -1):

You must do it like this

```
public class MyAsyncTaskgetNews extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        HttpURLConnection conn;
        URL url = null;


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
       url = new URL(params[0]);

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "exception";
            }
            try {

                conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(1000);

                conn.setDoInput(false);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
                String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

                // Open connection for sending data
                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(query);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();
                conn.connect();

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
                return "exception";
            }

            try {

                int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

                // Check if successful connection made
                if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    // Read data sent from server
                    InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);
                    }

                    // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                    return(result.toString());

                }else{

                    return("unsuccessful");
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "exception";
            } finally {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            mAuthTask = null;

            // result contains the response, do whatever u want to do
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {

        }
    }
```

Comment: i'm sorry maybe by mistake because i tried your solution and it is really similar to my code and it work fine ... thank you a lot